# Problem with reading text then put the text to the list and sort them in the proper way

Tags: string, split, strip

Open the file romeo.txt and read it line by line. For each line, split the line into a list of words using the split() method. The program should build a list of words. For each word on each line check to see if the word is already in the list and if not append it to the list. When the program completes, sort and print the resulting words in alphabetical order.

This is the question my problem is I cannot write a proper code and gathering true data, always my code gives me 4 different lists for each raw!

** This is my code**

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    line=line.rstrip()
    line =line.split()
    if line in last:
        print(true)
    else:
        lst.append(line)
        print(lst)
```

*** the text is here, please copy and paste in text editor***
But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief

Comment: Thanks for the Shakespeare at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the presence of individual words in the list, but rather the presence of the entire list of words in that line.

With some modifications, you can achieve what you are trying to do this way:

```py
    fname = input("Enter file name: ")
    fh = open(fname)
    lst = list()
    for line in fh:
        line = line.rstrip()
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if word not in lst:
                lst.append(word)
    print(lst)
```

However, a few things I would like to point out looking at your code:

1. Why are you using `rstrip()` instead of `strip()`?
2. It is better to use `list = []` as opposed to your `lst = list()`. It is shorter, faster, more Pythonic and avoids the use of this confusing `lst` variable.
3. You should want to remove punctuation marks attached to words, eg: `,.:` which do not get removed by `split()`
4. If you want a loop body to not do anything, use `pass`. Why are you printing `true`? Also, in Python, it's `True` and not `true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, honestly I am at beginning of the path. I made some mistakes and you mentioned them properly. Thanks for your comment. Good luck.

Comment: Happy to hear that! You may choose to *accept* my answer if it helped solved your question.